# Find $\bigcap _{ i=1 }^\infty (0,i)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I solve this one ?

Find $\bigcap _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ A_{ i } }$ and $\bigcap _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ A_{ i } }$ if for every positive integer $i$, $A_{ i }=(0,i)$, that is\quad the set of real numbers x\quad with $0<x<i$.

I don't have any idea what to do with this one

Answer (score 2):

$A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset\cdots$
So
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=(0,\infty),~~~~~\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=A_1=(0,1)$$

Answer (score 0):

$x\in\underset{i=1}{\cap}A_{i}\iff x\in A_{i}\text{ for all }i\iff0<x<i\text{ for all }i\iff0<x<1$

$x\in\underset{i=1}{\cup}A_{i}\iff x\in A_{i}\text{ for some }i\iff0<x<i\text{ for some }i\iff0<x<\infty$